# How to write to file from inside a recursive function

Tags: c, file-io

Programming noob here. Please check the below code... It's a brute force combination generator for a given vocabulary. It's not compiling. Can you please point out the error(S)? If possible please show me how to write a separate function for file and terminal output in this situation. Thanks for your time!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
static const char alphabet[] = "abcd";//vocabulary
static const int alphabetSize = sizeof(alphabet) - 1;
void bruteImpl(char* str, int index, int maxDepth)//main recursive function
{
    for (int i = 0; i < alphabetSize; ++i)
    {
        str[index] = alphabet[i];
        if (index == maxDepth - 1) 
        {
            printf("%s\n", str);
            fprintf(fp, "%s\n", str);// error 
        }
        else bruteImpl(str, index + 1, maxDepth);
    }
}
void bruteSequential(int maxLen)
{
    char* buf = malloc(maxLen + 1);
    for (int i = 1; i <= maxLen; ++i)
    {
        memset(buf, 0, maxLen + 1);
        bruteImpl(buf, 0, i);
    }
    free(buf);
}
int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp;//warning
    fp = fopen("output", "w");//warning

    bruteSequential(5);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please show us the exact error messages you get for exactly the fragment of code you show.

Comment: Why don't YOU try to compile it using a compiler? If you have a specific question, ask it.

Comment: Don't even bother doing file I/O inside the program.  Just write to stdout and let the shell handle redirections.   Stop thinking of file output as somehow different from terminal output.

Comment: Your problem (with the file I/O and recursion) is that you don't pass the output file stream to the recursive function, so it has no clue what you mean by `fp`.  Either (perish the thought) make `FILE *fp;` into a global variable or pass it as an extra argument to the function.  And do check that you succeeded in opening the file before you use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments. In order to use a file stream in your recursive function, you must pass an open stream to each function as an argument. Simply include `FILE *name` as an argument in each of your function declarations to make your output file available to your functions.

In addition to the `FILE *` arguments, there is no need to declare `alphabet` or `alphabetSize` as `static`. Both values are already declared with `file` scope and duration by virtue of being declare as `global` variables.

Not knowing the intent of your code, it is hard to determine if `i <= maxLen` should be `i < maxLen`. I suspect it is, but check.

With those taken into consideration, your code can be implemented as follows. Note in `main()` the `bruteSequential (alphabetSize + 1, fp);` has also been changed to remove the hardcoded value of `5`. You declared `alphabetSize` as global -- use it. Let me know if you have any further questions.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

const char alphabet[] = "abcd";            /* no need for 'static' already file scope */
const int alphabetSize = sizeof(alphabet) - 1;

void bruteImpl(char* str, int index, int maxDepth, FILE *fptr)  /* pass FILE * as arg */
{
    for (int i = 0; i < alphabetSize; ++i)
    {
        str[index] = alphabet[i];
        if (index == maxDepth - 1) 
        {
            printf("%s\n", str);
            fprintf(fptr, "%s\n", str);
        }
        else bruteImpl(str, index + 1, maxDepth, fptr);
    }
}

void bruteSequential(int maxLen, FILE *fptr)                    /* pass FILE * as arg */
{
    char* buf = malloc(maxLen + 1);
    for (int i = 1; i < maxLen; ++i)           /* check < maxLen instead of <= maxLen */
    {
        memset(buf, 0, maxLen + 1);
        bruteImpl(buf, 0, i, fptr);
    }
    free(buf);
}

int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("output", "w");
    /* you should validate fp is not NULL here */

    bruteSequential (alphabetSize + 1, fp);     /* pass alphabetSize + 1 & fp as args   */
    return 0;
}
```

**output (in ./output):**

```
$ ./bin/bseq
a
b
c
d
aa
ab
ac
ad
...
dd
aaa
aab
...
ddd
aaaa
...
dddd
```

Comment: That will do. Thanks a lot!